# Get array of values from site page by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, web

I need csv file like: "Region title","image filename", "href value" from the site page https://sbertrade.ru/rost_region. How to do this by jquery?

I tried to get the elements by this code:

```
$(".item").each(function(){$(this).children('img')});
```

But it shows me only .item class elements. How to fetch innerText from it, then add to this image src from child elements? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it with vanilla js:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

const getDataForItem = item => ({
    title: item.querySelector('.img-title')?.innerHTML,
    href: item.querySelector('a')?.href,
    src: item.querySelector('img')?.src,
});

const data = Array.from(items).map(getDataForItem);
```

And here's the jQuery version:

```
const items = $('.item');

const getDataForItem = function(item) {
    return {
        title: $($(item).find('.img-title')).html(),
        href: $($(item).find('a')).attr('href'),
        src: $($(item).find('img')).attr('src'),
    }
};

const data = $.map($(items), getDataForItem);
```

[jQuery find function documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/)